How to backup damaged DVD which is CSS protected
I had a burnt disc from the 2000s, I tried backing it up, but it had issues. So went out and purchased another copy, a box set in fact. It was released 20 years ago.
When I used dvdbackup some of the .VOB files had issues and wouldn't play.
I can't use ddrescue because it doesn't understand what is dodgy data and CSS confusion. The dvds seem to play okay with VLC. I can't find away to get around this, I know VLC has a convert feature, but it doesn't work.
Surely there is a way to use ddrescue with CSS or pipe out of something which can can open CSS dvds into something which can do error checking, like rsync?
This situation that 'you can have a CSS playing programme or a data recovery/backup programme but not both' seems crazy.

You say the DVD plays fine in VLC. Then, why would you think it's damaged?

Because some of the .VOB files were 'patchy' and would prematurely end when I played them individually. Also, I tried editing episodes out to be .mp4s using pitivi and it was hit-and-miss. The box set was manufactured 18 years ago, and the DVD I burnt was written 20 years ago and that certainly has deteriorated. Hence, there must be some way to open a disc (mitigate CSS) then ddrescue the data.

In my experience, after opening a CSS protected DVD with libdvdcss (let it be dvdbackup -I or anything else) once, you would be able to "raw read" (dd, ddrescue, cat, ...) the whole disc (until you have it ejected, IIRC). I don't know if it's the same case for all drives though. The raw/encrypted dump can usually be decrypted by libdvdcss/dvdbackup (-i can take a regular file), since nowadays it can determine the disc ID whatsoever (which is not included in the dump) by brute force attack in seconds.

Do you have libdvdcss2 installed?  VLC might be using its own decoder.  Check out k9copy.
